# How to get unique record from many to one relationship table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm stuck and can't find any help on this. What I'm trying to do is get the unique record by ***ID*** from ***STUDENTS_DETAILS*** table. ***STUDENTS_DETAILS*** table has many to one relationship with ***STUDENTS***.

```
var query = (from x in OracleDb.STUDENTS_DETAILS
             join y in OracleDb.STUDENTS on x.ID equals y.ID
             select new StudentViewModel()
             {
                 ID = x.ID,
                 APPLICATION_DATE = x.APPLICATION_DATE,
                 STUDENT_JOINED_DATE = y.STUDENT_JOINED_DATE,
                 SCHEME = y.SCHEME
             }).OrderByDescending(a => a.APPLICATION_DATE).ToList();
```

Comment: Use the Distinct() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider other factors when you want to get the unique records since you might have duplicate record of ID like on this example as mentioned by @**Rahatur** on his answer:

```
 { ID = 1, SCHEME = "A" }; 
 { ID = 1, SCHEME = "B" };
```

They might have duplicate record of ID, but they are unique since they have unique Scheme field. That is one of your consideration. Now if this is regardless of your needed result, and you just want to get the unique `ID` of your record, then you might want to try this:

```
var result = query.GroupBy(y => y.ID).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

This will get the First element of your sequence and will make sure you have unique `ID` on your record set results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have one to many relation between STUDENTS and STUDENTS_DETAILS, I am guessing the data in the STUDENTS_DETAILS are different for a student.

In that case for different data in the STUDENTS_DETAILS table the same student record would be loaded multiple times. Doing `Distinct` will not work. You have to do `GroupBy`.

Example:

`var results = from s in STUDENTS 
              group s.Detail by s.ID into g
              select new { ID = g.Key, Details = g.ToList() };`

For the following data:

```
 { ID = 1, APPLICATION_DATE = "2/2/2019", SCHEME = "A" }; 
 { ID = 1, APPLICATION_DATE = "2/2/2019", SCHEME = "B" }; 
 { ID = 2, APPLICATION_DATE = "3/2/2019", SCHEME = "C" };
```

You will get three rows instead of two due to the value in the SCHEME property. To get one row per student you have to decide how to group by all other properties other than the ID. e.g. take max length data and max date etc.